# Postman can't seem to find my backend api and I can't find out why

Tags: rest, api, asp.net-web-api, postman

I've written a backend api in .net and I would like to test my methods but when I open postman and try my different methods, it never works:

#### Could not get any response

There was an error connecting to xxx/api/videos

The strange thing is that if I click the embedded link, it takes me to the right page of my api and shows me the json that I expect (now I use this url as an example, I want to test a post method and I con't view this one in the browser). If any of you know what to do, let me know.

Comment: Check if the Postman configuration ignores SSL certificate warnings, since that is a common issue when dealing with backends with self-signed certificates. Also double check you're using the proper HTTP method, i.e. GET if that works in your browser.

Comment: Thanks! it works now that I disabled SSL certificate verification! @MarcSances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Postman Setting]

click here in settings, one pop up window will get open. There we have switcher to make SSL verification certificate. Switch to (Off).